# How to fix upload csv file in bigquery using python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

while uploading csv file on BigQuery through storage , I am getting below error:
**CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 5; errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for more details.**

In schema , I am using all parameter as string.

In csv file,I have below data:

**It's Time. Say "I Do" in my style.**

I am not able upload csv file in BigQuery containing above sentence

Comment: I do not know BigQuery, but in many cases with CSV-files you may have to escape " char with \" or you have to change CSV quote char from " to ' (or to regex all " chars in input/output strings to ' )  in order to get CSV data imported correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Does the CSV file have the exact same structure of the dataset schema? Both must match for the upload to be successful.

If your CSV file has only one sentence in the first row of the first column, then your schema must have a table with exactly one field as STRING. If there is content in the second column of the CSV, the schema must then have a second field for it, etc. Conversely, if your scheman has say 2 fields set as STRING, there must be data in first two columns in the CSV.

Data location must also match, if your BigQuery dataset is in US, then your Cloud Storage bucket must be in US too for the upload to work.

[Check here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#bigquery_load_table_gcs_csv-cli) for details of uploading CSV into BigQuery.

Comment: "It's Time. Say "I Do" in my style." this is a complete value for one field. For this field schema defined as STRING in BigQuery table schema.

Comment: yes and as there is only one field used in the CSV, then your BigQuery schema should have also exactly and only one field as STRING. Can you paste your schema here?

Comment: schema = [{'name': 'SUBJECT', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'nullable'},{'name': 'SUBJECT1', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'nullable'},{'name': 'SUBJECT2', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'nullable'}]

Comment: there are 3 fields defined in your schema, so that's what is causing the error. Either you must populate at least the first 3 fields of the first 3 columns in your CSV, or modify the schema in BigQuery so it has only one field, like so:


schema = [{'name': 'SUBJECT', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'nullable'}]

Comment: I have three fields in CSV file like below:

column name :subject , subject1,   subject2
Values: Email,    From,       It's Time. Say "I Do" in my style.

then also I am not able to upload.

Comment: I suggest you follow the flow in my answer and provide screenshot and more details if you need more help

Comment: @Pradeep so there must be something wrong with the CSV, are you sure you are using a file saved in Excel as CSV, with each part in a separate cell? if it's in a text file, then these values must be separated by commas.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all for a response.

Here is my solution to this problem:

> with open('/path/to/csv/file', 'r') as f:
>       text = f.read()
>
> converted_text = text.replace('"',"'") print(converted_text)
>
> with open('/path/to/csv/file', 'w') as f:
>       f.write(converted_text)